# Use a variable declared in a function outside that function

Tags: php

I have created a function using PHP which looks like this

```
<?php

function addImage($imageFolder, $imageName) {

    global $imageName;

    $imageName = 'stackoverflow'.$imageName;

    if (condition) {

        global $imageFolder;

        $imagePath = $imageFolder.''.$imageName;

        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $imagePath)) {

            return true;

        }

    }       
}

if(addImage('image/', $imageName)){

    echo $imageName;
    echo $imageFolder;
}

?>
```

The problem I am facing is that, I am able to get `$imageName` outside the function but unable to get `$imageFolder` ( `var_dump($imageFolder)` displays `null`). I am new to the `global variable` and I really don't know if I am using it correctly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that the `global` keyword doesn't make an existing variable a global one. Instead, it tells PHP that when you refer to a variable by that name, it should look in the global scope.

You have two options to fix this:

### 1. Use different variable names for parameters than you do for the globals

```
<?php

function addImage($imgFolder, $imgName) {

    global $imageName;

    $imageName = 'stackoverflow'.$imgName;

    if (condition) {

        global $imageFolder;
        $imageFolder = $imgFolder;

        $imagePath = $imageFolder.''.$imageName;

        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $imagePath)) {

            return true;

        }

    }       
}

if(addImage('image/', $imageName)){

    echo $imageName;
    echo $imageFolder;
}

?>
```

### 2. Use the [`$GLOBALS`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.globals.php) variable

```
<?php

function addImage($imageFolder, $imageName) {
    $imageName = 'stackoverflow'.$imageName;
    $GLOBALS['imageName'] = $imageName;

    if (condition) {
        $GLOBALS['imageFolder'] = $imageFolder;

        $imagePath = $imageFolder.''.$imageName;

        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $imagePath)) {

            return true;

        }

    }       
}

if(addImage('image/', $imageName)){

    echo $imageName;
    echo $imageFolder;
}

?>
```

### 3. Don't use globals (probably a better solution) [Thanks [Robbie Averill](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2812842/robbie-averill)]

```
<?php

function addImage($imageFolder, $imageName) {
    $imageName = 'stackoverflow'.$imageName;

    if (condition) {

        $imagePath = $imageFolder.''.$imageName;

        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $imagePath)) {

            return $imageName;

        }

    }  
    return false;
}

$imageFolder = 'image/';
if($imageName = addImage($imageFolder, $imageName)){

    echo $imageName;
    echo $imageFolder;
}

?>
```

Comment: Third option, don't use globals at all

Comment: @RobbieAverill Updated.

Answer (score 2):

You go the wrong way. You already have the values outside of the function. Assign them to variables to reuse them. `global` is used to access variables declared outside of the function. Example:

```
$myVariable = "hello"; 
function test() {
     global $myVariable;
     echo $myVariable;
}
test();
//output: hello
```

You can view $imageName outside of your function because you set it to a value after the global statement. But this really isn't the right way.

If you want to modify a passed variable, use a reference ( http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.whatdo.php )

You should do something like this:

```
<?php

function addImage($imageFolder, &$imageName) {

    $imageName = 'stackoverflow'.$imageName;

    if (condition) {

        $imagePath = $imageFolder.''.$imageName;

        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $imagePath)) {

            return true;

        }

    }       
}

$imageFolder = 'image/';
$imageName = "..."; // don't know where this comes from in your code.

if(addImage($imageFolder, $imageName)){

    echo $imageName;
    echo $imageFolder;
}
```